# Linear layout's background disappear once on child focus

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout

I have a search layout, let's say named `search_holder.xml` It's a horizontal linearlayout that contain a search icon, then an edittext for input, and a X icon to clear the input.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/button_search_images"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/tick_icon_distance">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/tick_icon_distance"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/search_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:hint="@string/search_google_images_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/search_text_size" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tick_icon_distance"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tick_icon_distance"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_x" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I include it in another layout:

```
<include android:id="@+id/search_block"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_right_margin"
                layout="@layout/search_holder"
                />
```

The problem occurs when I tap the edittext for the first time. The background of the linearlayout disappear (it became transparent).

Then when I tap outside, the background came back. Click the edittext again and nothing happens. It only happens once when the activity is first created.

This problem happens with API 21 and lower.

I tried to enable/disable hardware accelerator but it won't help.

I don't know if it's the version or am I missing something for the lower version.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT (Containing layout):

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="left"
tools:context=".MyActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

    <!--Custom ImageView for drawing multiple drawable to canvas-->
    <MyCustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/editorImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <!--This is for a frame on top of the CustomImageView-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false" />

<!-- Tools Layouts - The container of the tool set on top -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/vb_action_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/top_icons_shadow" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_top_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >


        <!-- The included layout here -->
        <include android:id="@+id/search_block"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_right_margin"
            layout="@layout/search_holder"
            />

        <!-- A few more button in the tool set -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_right_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/icon1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_right_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/btn2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_right_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/btn3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small_top_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/btn4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- A top left menu button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/slideMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xsmall_bottom_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xsmall_bottom_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: This layout is in landscape mode

Comment: Can you please post the layout xml where you included  search_holder layout?

Comment: Please check my edited question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by setting `android:focusable="true"` and  `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the root `LinearyLayout` of the holder `search_holder.xml`